# Постановка тире в предложении перед словами "Марк Давидович Сергеев"

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится или нет тире в предложении и почему: "Среди них и те, кто добился значительных успехов не только в инженерном деле, но и в творчестве, например знаменитый поэт и почетный гражданин города Иркутска — Марк Давидович Сергеев"?

Answer (score 1):

*Среди них и те, кто добился значительных успехов не только в инженерном деле, но и в творчестве, **например знаменитый поэт и почетный гражданин города Иркутска Марк Давидович Сергеев.***

В данном случае **нет причин для обособления приложения**. Согласно правилам Розенталя,  обычно обособляется приложение, стоящее **после имени собственного**. Приложение, стоящее **перед именем собственным,** обособляется в особых случаях (к примеру, если оно имеет добавочное обстоятельственное или пояснительное значение).

При наличии пояснительного значения **можно вставить *а именно*,** но в приведенном предложении такая вставка не представляется корректной.

Также следует учитывать, что оборот в конце предложения  (*например знаменитый поэт и почетный гражданин города Иркутска  Марк Давидович Сергеев*) **уже является обособленным.**